# React Hook Effects Error not able to deploy the website

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, web-deployment

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let val = window.ethereum.isConnected();
    if(val)
    {
      console.log("here");
      getAddress();
      toggleConnect(val);
      updateButton();
    }

    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', function(accounts){
      window.location.replace(location.pathname)
    })
  });
```

React Hook useEffect contains a call to 'toggleConnect'. Without a list of dependencies, this can lead to an infinite chain of updates. To fix this, pass [location.pathname] as a second argument to the useEffect Hook.

Please, could anyone help with fixing this error?

I tried fixing it by using // eslint-disable-next-line. The warning went away but I am facing issues deploying the website online. It is giving error messages.

Comment: what are the error messages

Comment: Line 58:3:  React Hook useEffect contains a call to 'toggleConnect'. Without a list of dependencies, this can lead to an infinite chain of updates. To fix this, pass [location.pathname] as a second argument to the useEffect Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps